# How do I implement an __add__ function in a class for n-Dimensional vectors?

Tags: python, class, vector, addition, args

I am trying to create a simple class for n-dimensional vectors, but I cannot figure out how to add 2 vectors with n arguments together. I cannot find a way to return a variable amount of arguments in the `__add__` function. In specific dimensions, this isn't too hard. Here's what it would look like for 2 dimensions:

```
class Vector2D:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return '({:g} , {:g} )'.format(self.x, self.y)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Vector2D(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

v, w = Vector2D(1,2), Vector2D(1,1)
print(v+w) #this should return (2, 3 )
```

Now I'd like to generalize this class to include all dimensions. I would probably use `*args` instead of x and y. Here's what that would sort of look like:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args

    def __str__(self):#not terribly important, but this function is quite ugly
        string = '( '
        for i in self.args:
            string += str(i)
            string += ', '
        string += ')'
        return string

    def __add__(self, other): #how would one do this?
        pass

v, w = Vector(2,3,4), Vector(1,1,1)
print(v+w) #I want this to return (3, 4, 5, )
```

I came up with some sort of solution, but it's not terribly efficient. Instead of loose argument, this version of my class uses a single list. I find this unsatisfactory however, so I came here to ask for a better solution. I have shared my mediocre solution down below:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, list = []):
        self.list = list

    def __str__(self):
        string = '('
        for i in self.list:
            string += str(i)
            string += ', '
        string += ')'
        return string

    def __add__(self, other):
        if len(self.list) == len(other.list):
            coordinates = []
            
            dimension = len(self.list)
            for i in range(dimension):
                newcoordinate = self.list[i] + other.list[i]
                coordinates.append(newcoordinate)

            return Vector(coordinates)

        else:
            raise TypeError('Can only add vectors of the same dimension.')


v, w = Vector([2,3,4]), Vector([1,1,1])
print(v+w) #this should return (3, 4, 5, )
```

In summary, I don't want to have to put the coordinates of a vector in a list. I can't think of a way to implement an `__add__` function though.

Comment: *I don't want to have to put the coordinates of a vector in a list.* - where should they be stored instead?

Comment: Why not use numpy arrays that have this functionality built in?

Comment: You can write the same `__add__` method you have shown for the `list` version also for the `*args` version, except you then have to return `Vector(*coordinates)`.

Comment: `return Vector([x+y for x,y in zip(self.list,other.list)])`.